# IOTA Whitepaper: What is n in Section 4?

Tags: iota-network, white-paper

I am trying to wrap my head around n in Section 4 of the IOTA Whitepaper.  I get that W is weight, but n does not seem to be defined.  Can anyone please help me understand it?

[image: Section 4 n]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `W^{(n)}` denotes the time it takes to complete a Proof-Of-Work of difficulty `n`, where `n` is a positive integer (of acceptable size, cf. first paragraph of Section 2).

Comment: Thank you.  Just out of curiousity what is n actually at this point in time?  I assume that IOTA wants to have a quick proof of work now and in the future?  In seconds not minutes?

Comment: @BillBisco MWM on mainnet is 14 and on testnet is 9. So you need 14 trits (9 respectively on testnet) to be zero of a Curl hash with 81 rounds. MWM used to be 15 initially but at that time Curl hash with 27 rounds was used.